# google people api - is there any way to add developer only data?

Tags: google-people-api

It seems the google people api does not support extended properties (user defined fields are supported but not extended properties) - see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113346916

Given this, is there any way to add developer only data to a person object?  I.e. some way to attach data via the api that the user cannot view or modify via their Google contacts?

Comment: The [Resource: Person](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person) has the property [metadata](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.PersonMetadata). Not quite what you need but maybe helpful? Otherwise your best bed is to "star" and comment on the existing feature request to increase visibility.

Comment: Reply from Google dev support:
Extended properties are now exposed as ClientData. See https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.FIELDS.client_data

Comment: That's good to know. Consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: good idea, have done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reply from Google dev support: Extended properties are now exposed as ClientData.

See https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.FIELDS.client_data